# Passing Config Content to SSH Command

Tags: shell, ssh, config

Normally we pass config file via `-F` argument:

`$ ssh -F my.conf`

Is there any way that I can pass content of `my.conf` to ssh without creating config file?

Comment: why do you use -F  every time instead of creating  ~/.ssh/config?

Comment: @minhtuannguyen because I have several config file and based on my requirements I will choice one of them. and actually my config file is dynamic.

Comment: @Cyrus Thanks, for multiple lines config like `Host Name` can I `cat` file content and pass it to `ssh` command? like this: `ssh -o $(cat my.conf)`

Comment: Then you are back where you started: `ssh -F my.conf localhost`

Comment: U could try `ssh -F <(cat my.conf)` under bash

Comment: @F.Hauri it shows error: `spawn ssh -F < (Host Server2
invalid command name "User"
    while executing`

Comment: `ssh -F <(echo Host Server2)`

Comment: @F.Hauri thanks, I've tried it `ssh -F <(echo Host Server2 User root HostName 192.168.1.1) Server2` but it sohws it: `Can't open user config file <(echo: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

You can write the config file content to a temporary file and delete it after using it for your ssh connection:

```
 mktemp | xargs -t -I {} sh -c 'echo "your ssh config content" > {}; ssh -F {} HOST; rm {}'
```